# Is it possible to use `gatsby-source-filesystem` as a "read-only" tool, and avoid creating static copies?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'm using `gatsby-source-filesystem` to traverse a directory tree and create links for the filtered nodes. Is it possible for me to run these GraphQL queries without also generating the `/public/static/[hash]` folders?

I expected to see some argument that could turn off the creation of `public/static/[hash]/filename.ext` for every node found by the query. I don't see anything [in the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/) about disabling those static copies.